# How to send data from simple digital device to an Android application wirelessly?

Tags: sensor, communication, wireless, data, android

I am trying to find a way to send measurements from a digital device (as the blood pressure device) to a mobile application that can analyse these data ..... How to send these measurements wireless efficiently?

**Please use a simple language**

Comment: Using the existing wireless interfaces your phone has? Can you name them?

Comment: There are e.g. ready-made RS232←→Bluetooth interfaces in the market. If your blood pressure monitor has an RS232 interface, you can easily add a wireless interface that way. Android phones can access those OOTB.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use "BLE" (Bluetooth Low Energy). There are a zillion very small, cheap kits on the market which you can use - many of which are programmable through simple means like Arduino SDKs. So if you have some generic device without any explicit interface, you can use the pins on the BLE device to program your own interface to your device (Blood Pressure device). It uses *extremely* little power and can operate for extended periods of time with a coin cell. Almost any modern phone would support the BLE protocol, and the APIs exist in major mobile OSes, so it makes for easy mobile integration.